# Mitigation after Spring Boot 2.7 EOL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-3

I know that Spring Boot 2.7 is ending its non-commercial support at [2023-11-24](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support). The support for Spring Framework 5.3 is ending more than one year later at [2024-12-31](https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework#support).

So for a project, which can't be upgraded to Spring Boot 3.0 in the short term, is it a good practice to add a dependency to the Spring Framework BOM in addition to `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.7.x` in the meantime?

This would of course only mitigate vulnerabilities fixed in Spring Framework 5.3, `spring-boot-dependencies` has many more dependencies that would need to be updated manually.

Comment: What Spring version is the project currently using? But yes, you might want to update to the latest version of 2.x before updating to 3.x in order to make the migration easier.

Comment: The dependency to the Spring Framwork is currently only transitive via Spring Boot. The latest version of Spring Boot 2.7 (2.7.17) is referring to the latest version of Spring Framework 5.3 (5.3.30).

Comment: Just add `spring.version` as a property to override the version being used, don't mess around with an additional dependency management import.

Comment: What's the point of doing each of them? Spring Boot 3 isn't compatible with Spring 5 anyways. Can you share a [mcve] showing what you want to do?

Comment: The question is not about updating to Spring Boot 3 without Spring Framework 6. That is a task which has to be done in the mid term. In the short term, it's just about updating to Spring Framework 5.3.31 and further, even if it is released after the last version of Spring Boot 2.7.

Comment: That isn't possible. Spring Boot 3.x doesn't work with Spring Framework 5.x.

Comment: I know, that's why I need to stay on Spring Boot 2.7 in the short term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot is somewhat tightly coupled with Spring Framework. Hence, you cannot use Spring Boot 3.x together with Spring Framework 5.y. Doing so will probably break some stuff and isn't supported at all.

This leaves you with 3 possibilities:

#### Staying at 2.x/5.y

You can continue using Spring Boot 2.7.

If you want to use newer versions of Spring Framework (future updates), you can use `<spring.version>` with future 5.y versions even though you are using the old Spring Boot 2.x version.

While that would mean using an unsupported version of Spring Boot, most of what you are using is probably Spring Framework which you can update this way.
Also, they would still publish public updates to Spring Boot in response to commercial update requests.

You might still want to start updating sooner than later so you can switch to a newer version earlier.

#### Migrating

At some point, you'll need to migrate anyways.

- First, update to, Java 17 and the latest version of Spring Boot and the latest possible versions of your dependencies. Make sure everything compiles and your tests pass.
- Then, run the migration tooling of your IDE (Spring Tools 4, tooling from IntelliJ Ultimate or [rewrite reciepts](https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/boot3/upgradespringboot_3_0)) in order to migrate to Spring Boot 3 and Spring Framework 6.
- Update your dependencies (if necessary)and make sure everything compiles.

  - You might need to adapt to some deprecations/removals.
- Finally, make sure all tests pass and test all your changes thoroughly.

Even though you say you can't update the project, you will need to do so eventually.

#### Switching to commercial support

Of course, you could also pay for commercial support but you will still need to migrate at some point.